How to Sync scroll between LazyColumn and LazyVerticalGrid in android Jetpack Compose?
For the design I am working on, it requires LazyColumn(used for stickyHeader) and LazyVerticalGrid.
Using the nestedScrollConnection and scroll states for respective composable, I was able to connect the scroll of both. When I scroll up the LazyVerticalGrid items, the items of LazyColumn scrolls up which is intended, but the items of LazyVerticalGrid also scrolls up in same ratio which pushes the items of LazyVerticalGrid behind the other items(items before LazyVerticalGrid) of LazyColumn.
What I want is - I want both scroll (or nested scroll) to work like one, similar to using single LazyColumn or Column with ScrollState (contents of LazyVerticalGrid starts scrolling only after the top items(items before LazyVerticalGrid) of LazyColumn goes out of view).
In short, I want both LazyVerticalGrid and LazyColumn scroll as one, not independently(which is default behavior of nestedScroll).
Here's the code,
    val lazyColumnState = rememberLazyListState()
    val mainScreenGridState = rememberLazyGridState()

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = -available.y
                if (lazyColumnState.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        if (delta > 0) { // Scrolling up
                            lazyColumnState.scrollBy(delta)
                        } else {
                            val gridMaxOffset =
                                mainScreenGridState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset - mainScreenGridState.layoutInfo.viewportSize.height
                            if (gridMaxOffset > 0 && mainScreenGridState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset >= gridMaxOffset) {
                                lazyColumnState.scrollBy(-delta)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyColumnState
        ) {
            item {
                Column(..) {
                ...
                }
            }


            item {
                CustomTitleAndSupportingHeadline(...)
            }

            stickyHeader {
                LazyRow() {
                    items(
                        items = ...,
                    key = { item -> item.id }
                    ) { item ->
                    ...
                    }
                }
            }

            item {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillParentMaxHeight(1f),
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(3), // manually 118.dp calculated from the content
                    state = mainScreenGridState
                ) {
                    items(..) { item ->
                    ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

If there better way to do this then I will be more than happy for suggestions.
